# Layout with Qt on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I am currently trying to develop a small demo app for Android using Qt but am failing miserably. This demo app should only contain a few labels and textfields where I can enter stuff, a connect button and upon connecting I want to show stuff in some other labels.

Problems I am facing:

- Layouting with QML seems to be quite un-intuitive and problematic with Android. It seems that my layouts are always packed and not doing, what I want them to do
- I have no idea how I can combine QMLs and C++ -> upon clicking the connect button I want to execute C++ code from a existing library (already compiled for Android using the NDK) and then update some GUI elements periodically if I receive new data. So I am assuming I need a thread for this and some kind of binding between my library and this GUI elements?

Since documentation seems very rare regarding this topic I would really appreciate some buzz-words for me to google to achieve my goals.

Comment: did you have a look at the example section of Qt documentation? At least for QML/C++ there should be plenty of examples to learn from.

Comment: If I remember correctly I only looked for specific Android examples and found none using simple controls like buttons or textfields. Should any QML/C++ be runable on Android?

Comment: According to the [Android Support Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/android-support.html): "Run Widget and QML applications on the device or emulator." So I guess you can go with tutorials for QML in general

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I will start looking at tutorials regarding this matter. If anyone has some examples that he thinks would be a good starting point, I would really appreciate it.